# How to store Double in a Type variable?

Tags: c#, typeof

I have defined the structure:

```
public struct ShapeAttribute {
    public string Name;
    public Type DataType;
    public double Value;}
```

But when I try to do the following

```
ShapeAttribute Radius = new ShapeAttribute {
    Name = "Radius",
    DataType = Double, // <-problem here
    DataIsValid = false};
```

"Double" is underlined and I'm told that

> 'double' is a type, which is not a valid argument in the given context.

I don't have a lot of knowledge of C# so I'm guessing I made a rookie mistake.

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: Can you try typeof(double) or typeof(Double) ?

Comment: Side note: please don't use `struct`s for this. Mutable structs are evil and can lead to unpredictable results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# syntax does not allow you to use a type name directly as a value. You have to use the `typeof` operator to get the Type object:

```
DataType = typeof(Double)
```

But this is probably not as useful as you might think. If the intention is to allow `ShapeAttribute` to support values of different types, then you have the problem that `Value` is still statically typed as a `double`, so `DataType` does not give you any additional information. Depending on what you want to achieve, you might need to use a generic type instead.